# Floppy Drive Power Input

Tags: power-supply, floppy

I would like to power a floppy drive without using a PSU out of a computer, and power it off something like batteries or a bench power supply, I know that the red wire is 5v and the black is ground and the yellow wire are 12v, however I want to know why there are two different power inputs the red and yellow wires.

I think there are 2 different power inputs as they control different things Ie the yellow (12v) controls the stepper motor inside and the 5v the floppy drive read head but I am not sure on this and would like some on to help clarify

Comment: Basically it is just like you said.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i want to make a musical floppy drive and was seeing if i could use just 12 volts to power it making my life easier as i only have to step the mother and not actually read anything from the disks

Comment: I am not sure about that. The yellow wire provides the reference voltage for the stepper motor. I don't think it's a control wire. The controlling takes place in some chip inside the floppy hardware.

Comment: What size floppy drive are you referring to?

Comment: FYI - floppy drives have two motors: one for the R/W head, and another for the spindle.  On 8" floppy drives, the spindle motor required AC line power.   *"power inputs as they control different things"* -- No, power simply provides power (i.e. electrical energy), there's no *"control"* through power.  Besides it's DC voltage, meaning it doesn't change.  How can something that doesn't change control something else?  @arminb - The floppy drive is just a transport device for the diskette.  The floppy controller is external to the drive.

Answer (score 3):

The 12V power is not used in 3.5" floppy drives for the last 25 years (I assume the question is about 3.5" formfactor). Everything is powered from +5V wire. The 12V is not used, it goes nowhere. That's why floppy drives fit USB enclosures, where only 5V is available.

Answer (score 1):

Yellow +12v does power the stepper motor. Red +5 does power logic+electronics. Since you will be using logical signals (5v logic levels) from an external floppy controller chip to control the floppy's stepper motor, both logic and stepper supplies are required - you need both +5v and +12v. And don't forget the two black ground wires - they are connected together inside the floppy drive.

Comment: This information about 12V is  at least 25-years old. All 3.5" floppy drives use +5V solely, the 12V on standard power connector simply not used.

Answer (score -1):

yellow (12v) controls the stepper motor inside and the 5v the floppy drive read head

Comment: Why are you answering your own question with incorrect information?